# Retain leading zero while converting from String to BigIntger

Tags: java

I am converting string to integer for mobileNumber.
Mobile number have leading zero while converting to BigInteger ..code is removing leading zero from String.
I want to retain leading zero. Can any one tell me way to achieve this. Below is my code.

```
public class MobileNumberStringToInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mobileNumber = "08305327";
    
        BigInteger mobileNumberBigInt= new BigInteger(mobileNumber );
 
    System.out.println("mobile number in string to mobileNumberBigIntger--"+mobileNumberBigInt);
    




    }

}
```

Comment: You can't - because a `BigInteger` just represents the number itself, and leading zeroes are irrelevant to the numeric value.

Comment: Why do you want to convert the phone number from string to big integer?

Comment: Mobile number have zero for the country. If zero is not there then sms is not sent to customer.

Comment: You should not use numeric types for telephone numbers. They consist of indicative data only, not numeric values, and leading zeros and various metadata characters are significant.

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of the number should not be important (but computers generally use binary-based representations, and not base-10). When you write

```
    System.out.println("mobileNumberBigIntger " + mobileNumberBigInt);
```

The `+` sign is actually using the default `toString()` to convert your `BigInteger` to a `String` that can be printed (because `System.out.println()` takes strings as arguments). So your problem is actually **"how to add leading zeroes while converting from BigInteger to String"**

To control *how* a `BigInteger` is transformed to a `String`, you use a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Assuming your numbers have 8 digits, you can use:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("00000000"); // 8 zeroes
System.out.println("mobileNumberBigIntger " + fmt.format(mobileNumberBigInt));
```

Note that

- you could have used a long (64 bit signed integers can represent 17-odd digits) to take up less space; in that case, format with `String.format("%08d", mobileNumberLong)`.
- it is better to use `String` instead of converting to/from numbers - because phone numbers have different lengths, and one format does not fit all use-cases.